# Crash when scrolling down the users list in app

Tags: bug, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the site name. (Stack Overflow)
2. Click Users.
3. Scroll down for a while.
4. Observe crash. (For me, it crashes at about the 90k rep mark when scrolling quickly, and ~67k when scrolling slowly.)

I'm using a Galaxy S4, Android 4.3.

Comment: Me it crashes as soon as it tries to display Jon Skeet's rep.

Comment: Can't repro as no android but +1 anyway. :) By the way if you scroll slowly, does all work well? If so probably the reason for the crash is that the app is sending requests "on demand" as you scroll and you overload the poor app/server/API.

Comment: I made it down to 60k before it crashed, but maybe I was scrolling faster than you =P  Repeated on 4.1.2 with RAZR MAXX.

Comment: @Shadow Actually I just tried scrolling slowly, crashes at about 67k. I'll remove the speed part.

Comment: So that's weird... maybe specific user causing this?

Comment: Yes I have noticed this scrolling issue in many section.

Comment: Is this still happening? I got different behaviour on v1.0.82 (beta): the app didn't crash, but some users were jumped (I think due to pagination from the API).