# Users between 12k and 28k are not shown

Tags: bug, android-app, users

**Android SE App** failed to show the users who are in between 28k and 12k.

In the app:

> [image]

In the desktop site:

> [image]

Comment: Please take some more time when posting to use proper tags, you're not new here. Thanks!

Comment: Can't repro in iOS app so it's not a problem with the API. Can you try to re-install the app to see if it helps?

Comment: No repro here in Android 4.4.2, app 1.0.26.

Comment: This happened to me on PPCG once - everyone from ~2.9k to 5k was cut off (or something like that). I can confirm; +1

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215304/crash-when-scrolling-down-the-users-list-in-app?rq=1, I think it has something to do with pagination from API result, or related issue.